# Ionic 1 https Forbidden 403

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework, https

I have a problem with Ionic 1. I'm using Codeigniter as my backend and when I post data it returns HTML code 403 (Forbidden) on my app and I don't know what to do.

I also added app transport security in Xcode, but it is still not working.

Comment: Check CSRF is disable in codeigniter or not

Comment: hi sir @PareshGami good day thanks for the response
ive checked the 
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
what to do

Comment: Please share the api endpoint so that we can try it.